# invert colors of application in X11

Tags: x11

I am aware of inverting X11 window using the following command

```
xcalib -invert -alter
```

However, I could not find a command for inverting the colors of an individual application.

I tried inverting the colors of an application by running the application inside Xephyr or Xnest and trying to run xcalib command inside of that, but it failed stating:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xcalib -invert -alter
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-VidModeExtension" missing on display ":1".
Error - Unable to query gamma ramp size
```

Then I learned that Xnest can be started with XFree86-VidModeExtension, and tried the same as follows:

```
Xnest -ac -br +extension "XFree86-VidModeExtension"
```

Then I tried xcalib -invert -alter command on the display :1 again. It failed

I am running the ubuntu VM inside Virtualbox and running dwm window manager in it

Is there any way to run xcalib inside a nested X

Comment: Some compositing window managers can invert colours of individual windows (I've just checked kwin and it can; I vaguely remember compiz being able to do it too).

Comment: started using links2 browser with -html-g-background-color 0x000000 and it is just beautiful :)

Comment: @n.m. Answers should not be placed in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

`compiz` can invert colors of individual windows.